# PHP Header redirect page is returned inside an alert window

Tags: php, header, window, openshift, alert

I am trying to redirect to a web page after a user login using PHP.

My PHP code is as follows:

```
    <?php
date_default_timezone_set ('AMERICA/SANTIAGO');   
$dbhost = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST').':'.getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT');
$dbusername = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME');
$dbpassword = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD');
$db_name = 'tuhoramedica';
$mysqlCon = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, "", $dbport) or die ("Disculpa, estamos teniendo algunas dificultades técnicas, por favor intentalo nuevamente más tarde. Gracias por tu comprensión.\n");
mysqli_select_db($mysqlCon, $db_name) or die("Disculpa, estamos teniendo algunas dificultades técnicas, por favor intentalo nuevamente más tarde. Gracias por tu comprensión.\n");
//Prevent SQL Injection
$usuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqlCon, $_POST['user']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqlCon, $_POST['pass']);
stripslashes($user);
stripslashes($password);
$sql = "select * from usuarios where username='".$usuario."' and pswd='".$password."'";
$result=$mysqlCon->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
    session_start();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    //echo "Bienvenido " . $row["nombre"]." ".$row["apellido"];
    $_SESSION["nr_usuario"] = $row["nr_usuario"];
    $_SESSION["nombre_usuario"] = $row["nombre"];
    $_SESSION["apellido_usuario"] = $row["apellido"];
    $_SESSION["mail_usuario"] = $row["mail"];
    $_SESSION["username_usuario"] = $row["username"];
    $_SESSION["autentica"] = "SIP";
    header("Location: http://tuhoramedica-chakana.rhcloud.com/filtro_horas.php");
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Lo sentimos, su usuario y/o contraseña no coinciden.";
}
$mysqlCon->close();
?>
```

The PHP code does the log in Ok and does even retrieve the selected file. The problem is that it doesn't display it as a web page but instead, it returns the page code inside a browser alert window:

[Check the snapshot of what's returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCSc0.png)

I have been surfing for a while now on the web for search of somebody else having the same problem but I have found nothing.

By the way, I am running my app on Openshift using PHP and Mysql.

Comment: What happens if instead of Location with uppercase L you put location ?

Comment: Have you tried it as a simple `header("Location....etc` without the `ob_start();` and `ob_end_flush();` ?

Comment: I've tried with location and as a simple header, neither work. It s not the browser either since I get the same problem on chrome

Comment: ob_end_flush(); should not be there as it sends data to the browser. If this is does not fix it maybe there is something earlier in your script causing the issue.

Comment: I've removed ob-end_flush() and edited the question to include the whole script. It still is not working...

Comment: I think I got the problem, I am posting the form using a js ajax post that on success returns 'alert(result)' so all returns are in the "alert" window.

Comment: I've solved the issue. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

> Returns a string with backslashes stripped off.

This block of code on it's own doesn't do anything.

```
stripslashes($user);
stripslashes($password);
```

I'm guessing you want

```
$usuario = stripslashes($usuario);
$password = stripslashes($password);
```

Error reporting may be outputting an error about `$user` and `$password` not existing, and messing up your header output.

**edit**

I noticed hidden comments as I posted the answer. Glad you solved your problem, but you may still want to address the above.